# Equivalent of saying "It breaks my heart"?

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

What's the Japanese equivalent of saying "It breaks my heart"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naturally it depends on context.

For specifically romantic heartbreak, there is [失恋{しつれん}(する)](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/98861/meaning/m0u/%E5%A4%B1%E6%81%8B/):

> 失恋から立ち直れない。
>   I can't recover from my heartbreak.

For more general heartbreak (such as the arrest or death of a friend or family member), there is the expression [悲嘆{ひたん}に暮れる{くれる}](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%82%B2%E5%98%86%E3%81%AB%E6%9A%AE%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B):

> お父さんの死で悲嘆に暮れました。
>   He was heartbroken after his father's death.